# How to save wget or curl terminal output to file

Tags: terminal, save, wget

I want to ask how save wget or curl output which is writing to terminal.
For example:

```
wget -O - "some file im downloading"
```

Now terminal shows me how much of file was downloaded, what is current download speed.
So I want to know how to save all these changing values to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status information of `wget` is always printed to stderr (channel 2). So you can redirect that channel to a file:

wget -O - "some file im downloading" >downloaded_file 2>wget_status_info_file

Channel 1 (stdout) is redirected to the file `downloaded_file` and stderr to `wget_status_info_file`.